# Finding out whether an object exists within a plist?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, nsarray, plist

If I have a plist which I have put into and array, which looks something like this

```
-Root
   -Item 0        Dictionary
      Name        String         Henry
      Kids        Array
         -Item 0  String         Lindy
         -Item 1  String         Paul
   -Item 1        Dictionary
      Name        String         Janet
      Pets        Array
         -Item 0  String         Snoopy
         -Item 1  String         Pebbles
```

How can find out whether each person has kids or pets?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can query NSDictionary with valueForKey:key
//returns nil, if valued for key is not present.

```
NSDictionary *person = read the person to this..

if(nil == [person valueForKey:@"Kids"])
{
  //has no kids..
}
else
{
 //has kids
}

if(nil == [person valueForKey:@"Pets"])
{
  //has no pets..
}
else
{
 //has pets
}
```